# ¿como hacer en android studio una aplicación que me muestre mi ubicacion actual y las escuelas cercanas? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, google-maps

tengo que hacer una aplicación que tendrá 2 pantallas, la pantalla A debe encontrar escuelas cerca de mi ubicación, en función del tipo de lugar "escuela" definido por google places y mostrarlas en la pantalla tanto en marcadores como en una lista, la pantalla B debe mostrar los detalles de la escuela seleccionada por el usuario en la pantalla A,

hasta el momento ya me muestra las escuelas cercanas solo me faltaría agregar la lista en la misma vista del mapa. alguna idea la agradecería por favor.

esto lo utilizo para mostrar detalles cuando das clic al marcador pero no me manda a la segunda actividad (actividad Detalle)

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        if (marker.equals(mMap)) {

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MarkerDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUD, marker.getPosition().latitude);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUD, marker.getPosition().longitude);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }}
```

ESTA es mi actividad Detalle

public class MarkerDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker_detail);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Extraer lat. y lng.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String latlng = String.format(
            getString(R.string.marker_detail_latlng),
            intent.getDoubleExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_LATITUD, 0),
            intent.getDoubleExtra(MapsActivity.EXTRA_LONGITUD, 0));

    // Poblar
    TextView coordenadas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latlng);
    coordenadas.setText(latlng);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}